# text-overflow in span element not cutting texta outside element width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div with 3 spans inside where the middle one should "compress", ie cut the extra text when the size of the div is small.

The result I'm looking for is

```
A Very lon... A
          ^ here it should get cut with "text-overflow: ellipsis;"
```

Somehow the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` is not being applied to the span.

Any idea what I am missing?

Tried with `width`, `display`, `overflow` and nothing seems to work... tested both Chrome and Firefox.

```css
div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

div span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#long-text {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>A</span>
  <span id="long-text">Very long text here....</span>
  <span>A</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You Apply css on span . but you have to appy it on div ,, so its work ,,,,  check My Snippet .. For Ans..

Answer (score 1):

`span` is an inline element. It has no width or height.so try `display:inline-block` for the `span` element.Then the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` will work

```css
div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

div span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

#long-text {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>A</span>
    <span id="long-text">Very long text here....</span>
    <span>A</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I see. And where is the `...` from the ellipsis cutting the text?

Comment: @Rikard increase the width of the span.Please check the snippet

Comment: @XYZ its Not a right way to increase the span width ... You have to apply css to text not overflow the the div .. border .

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar  Increased the span width to show the elipsis is working.Not to fix the overflow  .The code he has written for text overflow for span is already working

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar  Your code show how to add that to a the div. I showed why it is not working in that span.

Comment: width: 20px; due to this.. but if he used elipsis  in overflow.. then why its not work in 20px; ... i think its have to work in.. 20px .. also..

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar   Ellipsis also working in 20px.but it shows only dots because of the limited space to show a word

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is giving span block display

```css
div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

div span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#long-text {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>A</span>
  <span id="long-text">Very long text here....</span>
  <span>A</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as XYZ said span is an inline element. And you need to change it's display property to block or inline-block depending on the desired effect. In your case it will be

```
#long-text{
display: inline-block
width: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 width: 100px; 
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 }

span {

text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>A</span>
    <span id="long-text">Very long text here......</span>
    <span>A</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

change your padding to margin.

margin gives spaces outside your object while padding gives you spaces inside. text overflow will not consider it outside if it is still inside that padding